# Add styling to directory listing in tomcat 8

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

I struggle in adding providing a path to .xsl file that overrides globalXsltFile directory listing in Tomcat 8. I have tried to put my .xsl file in WebContent foler, WEB-INF and in just project folder, and providing path to them but that does not seem to work. 
This is how it looks now, with the .xlt script inside WebContent/script directory:

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the shown XML ends up in the `/WEB-INF/web.xml` of your `.war` file, replace `globalXsltFile` with `contextXsltFile`, and remove `/V1` from the value, so the given path is resolved relative to your webapp root.

The path of the `globalXsltFile` parameter is resolved relative to `catalina.base`.

The path of the `contextXsltFile` parameter is resolved relative to the webapp.

The path of the `localXsltFile` parameter is resolved relative to the directory being listed.

Exactly as specified in the [**Tomcat Documentation**](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/default-servlet.html#change).

Comment: Thats seem to work, only the script folder with xsl stylesheet had to be moved into WebContent